# Php/Perl/Python/Shell script to rename files based the presence of certain characters

Tags: php, python, perl, shell, unicode

in centOS 5.6, i need to recursively rename a series of files in /path.

the files that need to be renamed contain groups of special characters in lieu of accented chars. i mapped out the table for conversion [here](http://pastebin.com/MMbjJphU). (What kind of encoding was used here anyways?)

i have a guess that perl would be best choice for the task, but it could also be php/python/shell. would someone be kind enough to help me with such script?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

That's mis-encoded UTF-8. Use `convmv` for that.

```
>>> print u'Ãƒâ€œ'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
Ó
```

​

```
$ convmv --nosmart -f utf-8 -t cp1252 Ãƒâ€œ
Starting a dry run without changes...
mv "./Ãƒâ€œ"    "./Ã“"
Ã“ exists and differs or --replace option missing - skipped
No changes to your files done. Use --notest to finally rename the files.
$ convmv --nosmart -f utf-8 -t cp1252 Ã“
Starting a dry run without changes...
mv "./Ã“"   "./Ó"
No changes to your files done. Use --notest to finally rename the files.
```

Comment: ok! i have a list of path/to/files that need to be renamed. what do i need around convmv to accomplish that? i cant even paste 'Ãƒâ€œ' into SSH, it comes out different when I paste...

Comment: Use `find` to find the files (`-type f`) and pass them through `convmv` (`-exec convmv ... {} +`).

Comment: "find . -type f - exec convmv ???? {} +"
i cant paste chars from the left column into the shell or vi (it produces a diff result on each one of them)

Comment: `--nosmart -f utf-8 -t cp1252`  Add `--notest` once you've verified the output.

Comment: i get "file or directory not found" even if I copy and paste from the output of LS.

Comment: Why are you copying and pasting anything other than the command? `find` will find the files itself.

Comment: Now I get "cp1252 doesn't cover all needed characters for" a few times before convmv gives up!

Comment: So then those may be in a different encoding.

Comment: how do i find out which encoding it is in? [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16298/one-for-the-gurus-upgrade-to-3-x-messed-up-only-filenames-with-accented-chars) is more background on the situation.

Comment: from the OP http://pastebin.com/MMbjJphU. note that each code is displayed differently in Ultraedit, Notepad++ and SSH shell...

Comment: convmv doesnt seem to agree with that. see the entire list of filenames [here](http://pastebin.com/ycb194QU)

Comment: Which ones are convmv having trouble with?

Comment: Are these the result of the first convmv, or are they the original filenames?

Comment: MMbjJphU are the original filenames. sxDNUZ49 is the output of convmv

Comment: MMbjJphU is in CP1252. ycb194QU is in Latin-1. Your browser has confused things with the pastes, and you should really be using Latin-1 instead.

Comment: "iso-8859-1 doesn't cover all needed characters for"

I dont think its the browser. MMbjJphU is how Notepad++ displays and ycb194QU is how Ultraedit display the same exact file. see all the different ways these chars are displayed  at http://pastebin.com/SkFyc24Z (I verified that these do indeed appear in pastebin exactly as they are displayed in each place)

Comment: *sigh* And of course they can't all agree. What encoding does Ultraedit claim it's using?

Comment: i can "SET code page/locale" but i dont know where to view the code page/locale currently in use...

Comment: it was set to "C default code locale/page" and also to "prompt to change if different from default system code page". does that answer your question? ultraedit 13.20a

Comment: convmv itself tells me it is UTF-8

Comment: the only combination of to/from that doesnt err out is `find . -type f -exec convmv --nosmart -f latin-1 -t utf-8 {} +`, but it doesnt produce the proper output.

browser calls CAF%C3%89.jpg or CAFÉ.jpg, but it should call CAF%C3%83%E2%80%B0.jpg or CAFÃ‰.jpg, which is not a 404.

therefore the actual filenames are OK (see first column [here](http://pastebin.com/RtZH8s8N), they match what the file name already IS). im guessing the problem is how wordpress writes out the references when it pulls them from the DB.

Comment: Could I use convmv to just strip out all accents and weird chars?

Comment: You could try using `ascii` as a target to remove the characters, but I don't think it does transliteration for the accents.